# Tuning a tuned mass damper

Tags: classical-mechanics, vibrations

In order for a tuned mass damper to work effectively, its frequency and damping ratio have to be tuned according to the mass ratio of the damper and the whole system itself, such as by using the Den Hartog equation $f=\frac{1}{1+\mu}$.

Why does tuned mass damper need to be tuned in order for it to work effectively? Is it so that it does not result in overdamping, or are there other factors that contribute to the system? What does effectiveness mean for a tuned mass damper?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: look up the concept of "mechanical impedance".

Answer (score 1):

Why does tuned mass damper need to be tuned in order for it to work effectively?

A tuned mass damper damp a specific frequency therefore it place an antiresonance for the system at such a frequency.
If the system is multi dof you obtain a zero all the point and cross receptances with regard to the TMD attachment point.
It is "tuned" so it places the antiresonance at the correct frequency.
Changing the damping results in changing the range of frequency where vibration is absorbed, but also in reducing the effectiveness of the absorber, in fact the higher is the damping, the lower is the "negative amplitude" introduced by the new antiresonance.
Moreover, when you place an absorber you should know that you are introducing also some new resonance frequencies into the system therefore i suggest you to consider this fact.
A lot of effort has been done in this field in literature from several authors. You can find a lot of works on google scholar for example.